# Chinese encoding issue while listing files

Tags: java, encoding, solaris, cjk

I am running a Java application on a `Solaris10 with Chinese`. Now there are some files in a directory with chinese filenames. When I do `files = new File(dir).list()` where "dir" is the parent directory containing that chinese file, I get the result filename `files[0]` as **?????**(some junk characters).

Now the deal is that my programs **file.encoding** property is already set to **GBK** and I also do `Charset.isSupported("GBK")` and it returns true too. So where could be the problem. I am running out of ideas.

**NOTE:** I am not trying to print the filename anywhere or copy the file or something. I am simply openeing a stream to it, something like below:

```
files = new File(dir).list();
new FileInputStream(files[0]);
```

Now this gives me a FileNotFoundExcpetion, so I debug just to find that value inside files[0] is "??????".

Comment: Is the result of files[0] displayed on the console or in an output file (as junk)?

Comment: What Ryan Fernandes is hinting at is that there's a change that the directory name is read correctly by your program, but when you print the name out, the *console* will actually fail in displaying the characters correctly.

Comment: @ryan...no...I am not printing it anywhere. I am simplying using the filename to open a stream to it like new FileInputStream(files[0])...and it gives me a FileNotFoundException because the filename is ????

Comment: @thomas....i have debugged and checked that the program gets the directory name as "?????"

Comment: I understand the problem better now. I have updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it a good practice of doing it .
try setting the charset when you launch the jvm using : java -Dfile.encoding="" ...

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, I have already set the encoding as GBK from the command line

Answer (score 0):

ok can you try this instead

```
//String[] files = new File(dir).list(); 
File[] files = new File(dir).listFiles(); //use 'File' references instead.
FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream(files[0]);
```

This removes the dependencies on file names and works directly with the File object.

Comment: @ryan...well, it wont work either, because listFiles() essentially does the same thing internally i.e. use the list() method and then create a File object for each filename returned. So the exception will still come, but only now it will move two layers up in the stack frame. Nice attempt though:)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are maybe hitting the same problem as https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4866151

Usually this is caused when the file is created with one encoding and then tried to read via another.