# File.listFiles() mangles unicode names with JDK 6 (Unicode Normalization issues)

Tags: java, unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization, file-encodings

I'm struggling with a strange file name encoding issue when listing directory contents in Java 6 on both OS X and Linux: the `File.listFiles()` and related methods seem to return file names in a different encoding than the rest of the system.

Note that it is not merely the display of these file names that is causing me problems. I'm mainly interested in doing a comparison of file names with a remote file storage system, so I care more about the content of the name strings than the character encoding used to print output.

Here is a program to demonstrate. It creates a file with a Unicode name then prints out **URL-encoded** versions of the file names obtained from the directly-created File, and the same file when listed under a parent directory (you should run this code in an empty directory). The results show the different encoding returned by the `File.listFiles()` method.

```
String fileName = "Trîcky Nåme";
File file = new File(fileName);
file.createNewFile();
System.out.println("File name: " + URLEncoder.encode(file.getName(), "UTF-8"));

// Get parent (current) dir and list file contents
File parentDir = file.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile();
File[] children = parentDir.listFiles();
for (File child: children) {
    System.out.println("Listed name: " + URLEncoder.encode(child.getName(), "UTF-8"));
}
```

Here's what I get when I run this test code on my systems. Note the `%CC` versus `%C3` character representations.

OS X Snow Leopard:

```
File name: Tri%CC%82cky+Na%CC%8Ame
Listed name: Tr%C3%AEcky+N%C3%A5me

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02-279-10M3065)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01-279, mixed mode)
```

KUbuntu Linux (running in a VM on same OS X system):

```
File name: Tri%CC%82cky+Na%CC%8Ame
Listed name: Tr%C3%AEcky+N%C3%A5me

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.1) (6b18-1.8.1-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have tried various hacks to get the strings to agree, including setting the `file.encoding` system property and various `LC_CTYPE` and `LANG` environment variables. Nothing helps, nor do I want to resort to such hacks.

Unlike [this (somewhat related?) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423781/chinese-encoding-issue-while-listing-files), I am able to read data from the listed files despite the odd names

Comment: What's the encoding of your `.java` files?  I think you can use the `file` command to determine that.

Comment: The encoding of my example `.java file` from the `file` command: UTF-8 Unicode Java program text

Comment: Super-Excellent solution summary! SO would be an even better destination if more people did this.

Comment: EXCELLENT POST! That last quote about HSF+ is really good. The Apple keyboard shortcuts generate NFC but the filesystems normalizes to NFD. It’s still no help when you have one file named `"AB"` (Latin script), another anmed `"ΑΒ"` (Greek script), and a third named `"АВ"` (Cyrillic script).  Talk about security through gosh-that’s-hard-to-type-ness. :) I once had a machine names *wraeththu*, whom nobody could ever type the name of right to log into. Coulda been worse: could’ve spelt it like the original, which was *wrǽþþu* in Old English. :)

Comment: Really good post. I have also found that using the FSEvents API via JNotify exhibits related behaviour. For instance, when moving a file with unicode characters two create events occur: one for the filename in NFD e.g. "Tra?" and one in NFC e.g. "Trä". I tried normalising the first name sent through and it then appears identical to the second.

Comment: Is it too much to ask that Java keeps its frigging hands off my filenames? :(

Comment: @Trejkaz - It's not Java that's mucking with your filename, it's the HFS+ filesystem driver that is translating them to fully decomposed (NFD) form; and they are both valid Unicode/UTF-8 representations of the filename.

Comment: @StephenP So can you explain why listFiles() returns the strings as NFC? I know very well that HFS+ stores them as NFD, so why are they not returned as NFD?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Mac OS X (10.9.5 to be exact) on a mounted (remote) NFS volume. I would like to write a utility that renames NFD filenames to NFC filenames, and detects a name clash if both NFC and NFD filenames exist (I tried to create both files, it is allowed on my system). However, Java always return the NFC one to me. In fact, I have to use `java.nio.file.Paths.get(...)` to return a valid path, calling `exists()` on an element returned from `java.io.File.listFiles()` may return `false`! Any ideas?

Comment: I can't even get `Paths.get(URI)` to work... If the filename is in NFD it is reported as NFC, calling `Paths.get` still returns an NFC name. I'm really struggling to understand how this is not a bug (granted, we are off topic now as the OP was concerned with HFS).

Comment: @James Murty Was this fixed in java 7 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using Unicode, there is more than one valid way to represent the same letter.
The characters you're using in your Tricky Name are a "latin small letter i with circumflex" and a "latin small letter a with ring above".

You say "Note the `%CC` versus `%C3` character representations", but looking closer what you see are the sequences

```
i 0xCC 0x82 vs. 0xC3 0xAE
a 0xCC 0x8A vs. 0xC3 0xA5
```

That is, the first is letter `i` followed by 0xCC82 which is the UTF-8 encoding of the [Unicode`\u0302`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0302/index.htm) "combining circumflex accent" character while the second is UTF-8 for [`\u00EE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ee/index.htm) "latin small letter i with circumflex". Similarly for the other pair, the first is the letter `a` followed by 0xCC8A the "combining ring above" character and the second is "latin small letter a with ring above".  Both of these are valid UTF-8 encodings of valid Unicode character strings, but one is in "composed" and the other in "decomposed" format.

OS X HFS Plus volumes store strings (e.g. filenames) as "fully decomposed". A  Unix file-system is really stored according to how the filesystem driver chooses to store it. You can't make any blanket statements across different types of filesystems.

See the Wikipedia article on [Unicode Equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) for general discussion of composed vs decomposed forms, which mentions OS X specifically.

See Apple's Tech Q&A [QA1235](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1235.html) (in Objective-C unfortunately) for information on converting forms.

A [recent email thread](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2010/Feb/msg00177.html) on Apple's java-dev mailing list could be of some help to you.

Basically, you need to normalize the decomposed form into a composed form before you can compare the strings.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, it put me on the right track. See amended question with a summary of what I learned, and the specific solution (tl;dr -- use java.text.Normalizer)

Comment: I faced this kind of problem before. It's good to know the general theory behind it. Thanks!

Comment: @James: On a related not, I recently figured it would why Java’s `Pattern.CANON_EQ` flag wasn’t quite as much help as I had hoped  it should be. It seems a lot easier to match a casecharacter plus any marks in any order, something matching the string `NFD("égal")` with the pattern `"e\\pM*gal"`. The problem is that if you read a string like `"e\u0301gal"` or `"\u00E9gal"` from a config file, it only matches that literally, not with the `CANON_EQ` permutations.

Comment: Your Unicode values are wrong e.g. 0xCC82 is 'HANGUL SYLLABLE CYAENH' not "combining circumflex accent"

Comment: @paj28 - edited to clarify that the values are the utf8 _encodings_ of the unicode characters (so don't use the `\u` prefix, which is wrong for that) ... `0xCC82` **is** "combining circumflex accent" while `\uCC82` is the Hangul character. (prefix 0x vs prefix \u)

Answer (score 2):

### Solution extracted from question:

Thanks to Stephen P for putting me on the right track.

The fix first, for the impatient. If you are compiling with Java 6 you can use the [java.text.Normalizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) class to normalize strings into a common form of your choice, e.g.

```
// Normalize to "Normalization Form Canonical Decomposition" (NFD)
protected String normalizeUnicode(String str) {
    Normalizer.Form form = Normalizer.Form.NFD;
    if (!Normalizer.isNormalized(str, form)) {
        return Normalizer.normalize(str, form);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Since `java.text.Normalizer` is only available in Java 6 and later, if you need to compile with Java 5 you might have to resort to the `sun.text.Normalizer` implementation and something like this [reflection-based hack](http://www.koders.com/java/fid218162086362E4FD4F596825C25846E8D643182D.aspx?s=base64) See also [How does this normalize function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279910)

This alone is enough for me to decide I won't support compilation of my project with Java 5 :|

Here are other interesting things I learned in this sordid adventure.

- The confusion is caused by the file names being in one of two normalization forms which cannot be directly compared: Normalization Form Canonical Decomposition (NFD) or Normalization Form Canonical Composition (NFC). The former tends to have ASCII letters followed by "modifiers" to add accents etc, while the latter has only the extended characters with no ACSCII leading character. Read the wiki page Stephen P references for a better explanation.
- Unicode string literals like the one contained in the example code (and those received via HTTP in my real app) are in the NFD form, while file names returned by the `File.listFiles()` method are NFC. The following mini-example demonstrates the differences:

  ```
  String name = "Trîcky Nåme";
  System.out.println("Original name: " + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8"));
  System.out.println("NFC Normalized name: " + URLEncoder.encode(
      Normalizer.normalize(name, Normalizer.Form.NFC), "UTF-8"));
  System.out.println("NFD Normalized name: " + URLEncoder.encode(
      Normalizer.normalize(name, Normalizer.Form.NFD), "UTF-8"));
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  Original name: Tri%CC%82cky+Na%CC%8Ame
  NFC Normalized name: Tr%C3%AEcky+N%C3%A5me
  NFD Normalized name: Tri%CC%82cky+Na%CC%8Ame
  ```
- If you construct a `File` object with a string name, the `File.getName()` method will return the name **in whatever form you gave it originally**. However, if you call `File` methods that discover names on their own, they seem to return names in NFC form. This is a potentially a nasty gotcha. It certainly gotchme.
- According to the quote below from [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1235.html) file names are stored in decomposed (NFD) form on the HFS Plus file system:

  > When working within Mac OS you will find yourself using a mixture of precomposed and decomposed Unicode. For example, HFS Plus converts all file names to decomposed Unicode, while Macintosh keyboards generally produce precomposed Unicode.

  So the `File.listFiles()` method helpfully (?) converts file names to the (pre)composed (NFC) form.

Comment: This puzzles me. While I understand that strings should be normalized for higher level app logic, this forced normalization of filenames seems to imply that files written with the two different forms should be equivalent. But they aren't, are they? You could easily have two filenames with the same appearance but written with the different forms, and yet they are two separate files, so should be considered different. Right? So why would `File` force this on us? Does `Path` have the same behaviour?

Comment: @DanGravell: Well, in the filesystems the OP dealt with, filenames are converted to normalized unicode. So, for a useful comparison both inputs must be normalized to NFC or NFD, which of them doesn't matter and no data is lost. There are other filesystems which don't do any such conversions though, just look at standard Linux filesystems. There, doing any kind of text-normalization is lossy.

Comment: Yes, the scenario I'm considering is mounting a remote disk over CIFS or NFS, say, to a Mac. I have been looking at this, and `File` reports the filename with NFC even if I have renamed the file to be NFD. A subsequent `exists()` fails. Am I doing something dumb or overlooking something? I can't help but think `File` is broken in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something similar before. People that uploadde files from their Mac to a webapp used filenames with é.

a) In OS that char is normal e + "sign for ´ applied to the previous char"

b) In Windows it's a special char: é

Both are Unicode. So... I understand you pass the (b) option to File create and at some point Mac OS converts it to the (a) option. Maybe if you find the double representation issue over the internet you can get a way to handle both situations successfully.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well, in fact, it's happening the opposite. You type the Java file [original name] with your Mac keyboard the (a) option and the system converts it [at file creation time] to the (b) option.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the right track. I added a discussion to my question that expands a little on the different Unicode forms and when you get each kind from `File` methods

Answer (score 0):

On Unix file-system, a file name really is a null-terminated byte[].  So the java runtime has to perform conversion from java.lang.String to byte[] during the createNewFile() operation. The char-to-byte conversion is governed by the locale.  I've been testing setting `LC_ALL` to `en_US.UTF-8` and `en_US.ISO-8859-1` and got coherent results.  This is with Sun (...Oracle) java 1.6.0_20.  However, For `LC_ALL=en_US.POSIX`, the result is:

```
File name:   Tr%C3%AEcky+N%C3%A5me
Listed name: Tr%3Fcky+N%3Fme
```

`3F` is a question mark. It tells me that the conversion was not successful for the non-ASCII character.  Then again, everything is as expected.

But the reason why your two strings are different is because of the equivalence between the \u00EE character (or `C3 AE` in UTF-8) and the sequence i+\u0302 (`69 CC 82` in UTF-8). \u0302 is a combining diacritical mark (combining circumflex accent). Some sort of normalization occurred during the file creation.  I'm not sure if it's done in the Java run-time or the OS.

NOTE: I took me some time to figure it out since the code snippet that you've posted do not have a combining diacritical mark but the equivalent character `î` (e.g. `\u00ee`).  You should have embedded the Unicode escape sequence in the string literal (but it's easy to say that afterward...).

Comment: Your point about the equivalence of two different Unicode forms is exactly right. Interestingly, if I had included the explicit \u code for a combined/composed diacritical in the example it would have obscured the differences I was seeing in my real app. A case where doing it wrong worked out well

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you just have to instruct `javac` what encoding to use to compile the `.java` file containing the special characters with since you've hardcoded it in the source file. Otherwise the platform default encoding will be used, which may not be UTF-8 at all.

You can use the VM argument `-encoding` for this.

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 com/example/Foo.java
```

This way the resulting `.class` file will end up containing the correct characters and you will be able to create and list the correct filename as well.

Comment: Although the Unicode file name is hard-coded into the sample program, my real program sources data from the file system or a web service. No hard-coded strings are involved. I did try the `-encoding` option with my example code but it didn't make a difference there either.

Comment: After being burned the hard way too many times, I always include `-encoding UTF-8` on the compile line, and make sure the top of the file has a comment that the file is in UTF-8 in case the file and its makefile should become separated. I also always run with jvm arg of `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`, because I got too tired of seing my nice Java characters mutilated with nary an exception raised.

Answer (score -2):

An alternative solution is to use the new java.nio.Path api in place of the java.io.File api which works perfectly.